# Logout redirect url can't find a view

Tags: python, django, view, refresh

So, here are my files:

**settings.py**

```
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'refresh'
```

**views.py**

```
def about(request):
    return render(request, 'about.html', {})

def refresh(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get("HTTP_REFERER"))
```

**The problem:** If I set `LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'about'`, it works fine. Also if I add the code from **refresh** view to **about** view, it works fine too. However, when I set `LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'refresh'` I'll get the error 'View name was wrong'. I don't understand why I get this error.

**P.S.** If there is another way to refresh the page after log out, feel free and tell me it.

Comment: can you please update your `views.py` file code ?

Comment: update what? i didn't get it

Comment: sorry, I mean to say update your question with `urls.py` file code .

Comment: oh, I got it. logout_redirect_url tries to find the URL with the name 'refresh'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the name which you have given in your `urls.py` file. You have passed `refresh` in `LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'refresh'` which don't match the name with `urls.py`

So either you change the name in `urls.py` file or change in `setting.py` file.

Answer (score 0):

**settings.py**

```
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'refresh'
```

You need to add in **settings/urls.py** file :-

**settings/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='your_template_name.html'), name='logout'),
```